# Putting an image on a specific page eg page 5

Tags: graphics, page

I am trying to fix a image on a specific page (eg page 5) the "problem" is the way my document is set up is a main.tex that compiles a lot of sub files. And if possible I want the image to always stay on that given page.

Best regards
Frozzendeth

Here is my code

```
\input{latex/settings/statics.tex}
\input{latex/settings/preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

\subfile{latex/forrest/f.tex}
\newpage
\subfile{latex/forrest/s.tex}
\newpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

% FORREST
\subfile{latex/forrest/k.tex} 
\newpage
\subfile{latex/forrest/H.tex} 
\newpage
\subfile{latex/forrest/M.tex}
\newpage
\newpage\subfile{latex/forrest/Hh.tex}
\newpage
\subfile{latex/forrest/V.tex}
\newpage
\subfile{latex/forrest/C.tex}

\newpage
```

Comment: your posted code does not help anyone answer the question as no on can run it, but all the `\newpage` suggests that you have all manual page breaking, so what is the problem? just put `\includegraphcs{...}\newpage` after the 4th `\newpage`.

Comment: I'm sure I've done this before, but can't find it.  Closest is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621674/tikz-draw-on-specific-pages-not-all-pages