# Put a picture in bottom right, fading with text if there is any

Tags: formatting

- In a document, I'd like to have, on certain pages, a picture in the
  bottom right corner.
- I'd like the picture to not interfere with text
  (it can be displayed behind the text if there is text in the way).
- I tried this, but every time, I see only a part of the picture.
- Can you help me out so that the bottom-right corner of the picture coincides with the bottom right corner of the page?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
%\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.3,inner sep=0pt anchor=south east]  at (current page.south east)
{\includegraphics{./images/nico/Le-petit-Nicolas-1.jpg}};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621674/tikz-draw-on-specific-pages-not-all-pages