How to insert an image at a specific page number
I would like to insert an image by using package tikz at a desired page.
For example, I want this image to appear at page 3 (must be page 3), despite other contents are going to change freely.
Any suggestions for this?
Thank you.
PS. Precisely, the image is a header on my cv and I just want it to appear at some pages not all.
\newcommand\Header[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[accent_color]
  (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=50pt]current page.north east|-current page text area.north east) --
  ([yshift=50pt,xshift=-3cm]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
  ([yshift=10pt,xshift=-5cm]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
  ([yshift=10pt]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle;
\node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=west,
  xshift=0.7cm,yshift=-0.32cm] at (current page.north west)
  {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont {#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


Should the image be a background image (like a watermark) or a normal object in the main text contents? If it's the latter, where to place it? top, middle or bottom in page 3?

@Stephen I've just updated the question. It's like a watermark just appearing on some pages.

For a header, you can use \AddToHoo{shipout/background}{...} and test \value{page}.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621674/tikz-draw-on-specific-pages-not-all-pages

you can simply put it in the page head using fancyhdr or similar package, suurounded by \ifnum\value{page}=3 tikz here \fi
